# Making sense of loss and accuracy curves

Tags: deep-learning, classification, training, loss-function, accuracy

This is an issue that I have come across over and over again. Loss (cross-entropy in this case) and accuracy plots that do not make sense. Here is an example:
[image: Training and validation loss and accuracy plots]
Here, I’m training a ReNet18 on CIFAR10. Optimizer is SGD with 0.1 learning rate, 0.9 Nesterov momentum, 1e-4 weight decay. The learning rate is decreased to a ⅕ at epochs 60, 120, 160.

- Initially the curves are all nice and dandy; meaning training and
  validation loss are decreasing and accuracies are increasing.
- Around epoch 65~70 you see signs of overfitting; as val. loss starts
  increasing and val. accuracy starts decreasing (the **red** box). There
  is still nothing strange here.

Now there are two things that don’t make sense to me:

1. After epoch 120 (where LR is decreased) val. loss and accuracy start
   improving for a couple of epochs (the **green** box). Why would
   decreasing the learning rate suddenly improve validation performance
   of a model that was already overfitting?! I would expect the drop in
   LR to actually accelerate overfitting.
2. After epoch ~125 (the **blue** box) loss starts going up but accuracy keeps
   improving. I understand that loss could go up while accuracy stays
   constant (by the model getting more confident in its wrong
   predictions or less confident in its correct predictions). But I
   don’t get how accuracy can improve while loss goes up.

Answer (score 3):

Just a couple of points below

- Red box: In strict terms, overfitting takes place when the model is doing better in the training than the validation set. And so, I would say here it starts earlier than what is denoted in red and it probably does relate to the model finding better parameters that only apply to the training set. Of note, no significant train loss decrease.
- Green box: In training, significant drop in the loss. This discovery of a significantly better minima means it may also apply in the validation set and it is actually reflected in the val loss curve. Despite that, the loss is no better than the checkpoint at the beginning of the red box.
- Blue box: Loss and accuracy are not co-dependent metrics. Whereas accuracy is a measure of the number of correct guesses (how many), the loss is a measure of distance from correct given a data point (how far off).

Generally, smaller LR means the model has less "freedom" to hop very far around in the feature space. And so there are fewer chances to see significant and fast loss decrease. As you suggest, there is a slight upward overfitting trend in your val loss but is as significant or fast as the smaller LR allows in training.

Also, note that your train loss is higher than val loss for a good amount of your training (~55th epoch). You may want to investigate how your model is regularised as this may affect your learning curves in ways that may help you infer diagnostics better. E.g. in PyTorch, train loss between model states (model.train() and model.eval()) differ significantly.

Answer (score 0):

The loss is the sum of errors based on your train and validation datasets, whereas the accuracy is the percentage of good results obtained with the validation dataset.

So, if your loss is decreasing and your accuracy is increasing, it means that it has worse results in your train data sets but better ones in your validation dataset.

There is probably a way to define the learning criteria, focussing more on loss or accuracy, but I don't know how it works.

Comment: That makes sense but the question was how to explain *increasing* loss while accuracy is *increasing* too.

Comment: This event happens when the train accuracy is very high (97%), which could be an overfitting scenario. Furthermore, the fact that the learning rate is very low cannot improve the generalization on the validation dataset. Of course, it's just a hypothesis as I don't have all the details of the experience.